# Sort data by month, then year

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
                        Table Folder

      Column       |           Type           |                              Modifiers                          
-------------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------
 ID                | integer                  | not null default 
 Name              | character varying        | not null
 Size              | bigint                   | not null
 Timestamp         | timestamp with time zone |
```

attempting to get a count for all files uploaded in 2014. And monthly count for that same year.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  "File" WHERE "Timestamp" >  '2014-01-01 21:53:23+08'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(Timestamp, 'Mon') AS month,
       COUNT(*) AS fileCount
FROM File
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Timestamp) = 2014
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(Timestamp, 'Mon')
```

If you wanted a report which shows a monthly breakdown across multiple years, then you can slightly modify the above query:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(Timestamp, 'Mon') AS month,
       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Timestamp) AS year,
       COUNT(*) AS fileCount
FROM File
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Timestamp) IN (2014, 2015, ...)
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(Timestamp, 'Mon'),
         EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Timestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your own query, it seems you want to consider the timestamps of 2014 as seen from timezone GMT + 8 hours (Singapore, Hongkong or whatever) and count accordingly. I think the query should hence be:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM "Timestamp" AT TIMEZONE 'GMT-8'), COUNT(*)
FROM "File"
WHERE "Timestamp" >= timestamp with timezone '2014-01-01 00:00:00+08'
  AND "Timestamp" <  timestamp with timezone '2015-01-01 00:00:00+08'
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM "Timestamp" AT TIMEZONE 'GMT-8')
ORDER BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM "Timestamp" AT TIMEZONE 'GMT-8');
```

As I don't use any function on "Timestamp" in the where clause, an index may more likely be used to speed up the query (provided of course there *is* an index on the "Timestamp" column).

But I must admit timezones always confuse me. Why is it '+08' (plus sign) when I talk about Hongkong in datetime literals and 'GMT-8' (minus sign) when I want to convert to Hongkong time. It should be correct, though.